# updatepanel not updating html

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel

I've the following code:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="upanel1" >
        <ContentTemplate >
            <div id="west" class="x-hide-display" style="background-color: #9eb5bc; height: 100%;">

                <ul id="list_0" runat="server">
                </ul>
            </div>
        </ContentTemplate>
        <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger  ControlID ="btnImages"/>
        </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

and the server code is:

```
 list_0.InnerHtml = strPhotos.ToString()
```

My server code is executing but the page's html is not being updated. Please tell me what's wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I change my code to 
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me.upanel1, Me.GetType(), "saf", "$get('" + list_0.ClientID + "').innerHTML=""" + strPhotos.ToString() + """", True)

and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing, as far as I can see.

Anything in your css on the div that could be hiding it? i.e `class="x-hide-display"` looks suspcious.

Other than, that, are you running your `list_0.InnerHtml = strPhotos.ToString()` code in a method called by the button's click event?